# Why can't create Bitmap in LoadQueue's fileload event?

Tags: createjs

I am tryting to create a Bitmap and add it to the stage, but it doesn't work.

```js
this.queue.on("fileload", function(event) {
   if(event.item.id == "bg") {
   var bg = new createjs.Bitmap(this.queue.getResult("bg"));// doesn't work here！
}
   
}, this);
```

However, if I do this in the complete handler it works:

```js
 this.queue.on("complete", function(event) {
   var bg = new createjs.Bitmap(this.queue.getResult("id"));
   this.stage.addChild(bg); //works out and no error
 }, this);
```

Thanks very much for helping me!!

Comment: In the fileload event, use `event.result` instead. Your approach SHOULD work though.

Comment: Thx very much! You are right.